# PromiseKit: calling when(fulfilled:) with array of different type of Promise

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, promisekit

I have an array of Promise of different type. In this particular case `Promise<URL>` and `Promise<UIImage>` which I want to provide to `when(fulfilled:)`

As an example:

```
let fileName = "somefilename"

 let videos: [URL] = selectedItems.compactMap { guard $0.isVideo else {return nil}; return URL(string: $0.url) }
 let images: [URL] = selectedItems.compactMap { guard !$0.isVideo else {return nil}; return URL(string: $0.url) }
 let videoRequests = videos.map { RemoteDownloadManager.shared.downloadVideo(from: $0, withName: fileName) }
 let imgRequests = images.map {RemoteDownloadManager.shared.downloadImage(from: $0)}
```

I have two arrays of promises, but of different types: `[Promise<UIImage>]` and `[Promise<URL]`.

Is there a way to call `when(fulfilled)` with a combined, casted, array?

```
when(fulfilled: [imgRequests, videoRequests])
        .done { items in
                  // [...]
}
```

This won't compile (Obviously) with error: `Cannot invoke 'when' with an argument list of type '(fulfilled: [Any])'`

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by cast you array like this:

```
let promiseArray = [promise1, promise2] as! [Promise<Any>]
when(fulfilled: promiseArray).done { items in
                  // [...]
}
```